# VS Code - enable solution wide analysis?

Tags: visual-studio-code, analysis, solution

How can I enable something similar to solution wide analysis from Visual Studio 2017 in Visual Studio Code?

VS Code is able to analyse files when they are opened in the editor and show me a little error or warning symbol in the bar at the bottom of the application. But is there any option (or extension) to enable that feature "solution wide", i.e. when no file is opened in the editor?